# Format for registration of account in firebase via expo and how do i code my code to catch errors when creating new user via app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, expo

firebase.js:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ****,
  authDomain: ****,
  projectId: ****,
  storageBucket: ****,
  messagingSenderId: ****,
  appId: ****
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth()
```

loginScreen.js

```
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const handleSignUp = async () => {
        const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        console.log(user);
      }
```

New error appears when I key in the following: Email: Test@test.com, password:test

[image]

I have also refresh the firebase authentication page, no new user is added it. Also, I am referring to the guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ql4J6SpLXZA and in the video, the creator used 'matt@test.com' for email and it worked but when I try to do the same it has the warning problem and it is not synced in the firebase authentication table

1. How can I solve this problem?
2. Also, in this case, how can I code my loginscreen.js to catch when register fail?
   I really need some help/advice on this. Thank you!

LoginScreen.js (Entire thing)

```
import { KeyBoardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import KeyboardAvoidingView from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/KeyboardAvoidingView'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'


const LoginScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    const navigation = useNavigation()

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user){
                navigation.replace("Home")
            }
        })

        return unsubscribe
    })

    const handleSignUp = async () => {
        try {
        if (email && password) {
           const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
           console.log('Registered as :' , user.email);
          }
        } catch (error) {
           console.log({error});
        }
    }

    const handleLogin = async () => {
        try {
        if (email && password) {
           const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
           console.log('Logged in as :' , user.email);
          }
        } catch (error) {
           console.log({error});
        }
    }


    
        
    
    return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView  //To prevent keyboard from blocking the writing area
        style={styles.container}
        behavior = "padding"
    >  
        <View style = {styles.inputContainer}> 
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Email"
                value={email}
                onChangeText ={text => setEmail(text)}
                style = {styles.input} 
            />         
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Password"
                value={password}
                onChangeText ={text => setPassword(text)}
                style = {styles.input} 
                secureTextEntry //Hide password
            />         
        </View>   
        
        <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {handleLogin}
                style = {styles.button}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {handleSignUp}
                style = {[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>                       
    </KeyboardAvoidingView> 
  )
}

export default LoginScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ //To make the text area for username and password to be center. If not it will be at the top left hand corner
    container:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center',
    },
    inputContainer:{
        width: '80%'
    },
    input:{ //Not working?
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 10, //make edge more circle
        marginTop: 5, //Spacing between the input boxes

    },
    buttonContainer:{
        width: '60%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    button:{
        backgroundColor: '#0782F9',
        width: '100%',
        padding: 15, //Making the button enlarge in horizontal and vertical
        borderRadius: 10,
        alignItems: 'center', 

    },
    buttonOutline:{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginTop: 5,
        borderColor: '#0782F9', 
        borderWidth: 2, //Without the width, the colour won't show
    },
    buttonText:{ //For the login button
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight:'700',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    buttonOutlineText:{ //For the register button
        color: '#0782F9',
        fontWeight:'700',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
})
```

Comment: Can you try `console.log(email, password)` before `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` ? and check if the values are valid

Comment: Yup it is valid. Sorry for the false alarm. I attempted to restart the server and it somehow work by telling me what is the error.  It seems the email in this case is okay but the password is too short. Is there some form of way to show like "Password not valid" in the app instead of all those different console warning? This is because I have to  showcase the app to other people.

Comment: You can check length of the password before using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`. If it's short then alert the user about it else continue.

Comment: I add some code to make it less able to crash and if you need to check the length you can add it to the condition when I check for password and email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid crashes I prefer you add try catch to your code like this:

```
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const handleSignUp = async () => {
        try {
        if (email && password) {
           const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
           console.log(user);
          }
        } catch (e) {
           console.log({e});
        }
     }
```

For error messages:

```
import { KeyBoardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import KeyboardAvoidingView from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/KeyboardAvoidingView'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'


const LoginScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
    const navigation = useNavigation()

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user){
                navigation.replace("Home")
            }
        })

        return unsubscribe
    })

    const handleSignUp = async () => {
        try {
        if (email && password) {
           setShowError(false);
           const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
           console.log('Registered as :' , user.email);
          }
        } catch (error) {
           console.log({error});
           setShowError(true);
        }
    }

    const handleLogin = async () => {
        try {
        if (email && password) {
           const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
           console.log('Logged in as :' , user.email);
          }
        } catch (error) {
           console.log({error});
        }
    }


    
        
    
    return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView  //To prevent keyboard from blocking the writing area
        style={styles.container}
        behavior = "padding"
    >  
        <View style = {styles.inputContainer}> 
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Email"
                value={email}
                onChangeText ={text => setEmail(text)}
                style = {styles.input} 
            />         
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Password"
                value={password}
                onChangeText ={text => setPassword(text)}
                style = {styles.input} 
                secureTextEntry //Hide password
            />         
        </View> 
        {showError && <View style={styles.error}>
          <Text>Wrong username or password</Text>
  </View>}
        
        <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {handleLogin}
                style = {styles.button}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {handleSignUp}
                style = {[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>                       
    </KeyboardAvoidingView> 
  )
}

export default LoginScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ //To make the text area for username and password to be center. If not it will be at the top left hand corner
    container:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center',
    },
    inputContainer:{
        width: '80%'
    },
    input:{ //Not working?
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 10, //make edge more circle
        marginTop: 5, //Spacing between the input boxes

    },
    buttonContainer:{
        width: '60%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    button:{
        backgroundColor: '#0782F9',
        width: '100%',
        padding: 15, //Making the button enlarge in horizontal and vertical
        borderRadius: 10,
        alignItems: 'center', 

    },
    buttonOutline:{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginTop: 5,
        borderColor: '#0782F9', 
        borderWidth: 2, //Without the width, the colour won't show
    },
    buttonText:{ //For the login button
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight:'700',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    buttonOutlineText:{ //For the register button
        color: '#0782F9',
        fontWeight:'700',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
   error: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      padding: 16,
      textAlign: 'center'
   },
})
```

Comment: Hi, I realise this is just appearing in terminal that is running the server. I want to make it happen on the APP itself. Like after i click register and like for example the password is too short, can it come out with a window or like some lines on the APP that tells the user password is not acceptable?

Comment: On the catch, you can show an alert or a toast to the user or view anything you like

Comment: Oh okay. Is it possible on showing me how the code would look like? Thank you !

Comment: Can you add your whole login screen code so I can make an edit on it?

Comment: Sure, I have just added in. Its not really a very good login screen for now.

Comment: I've update it my answer with an example you can reDesign it and make it what ever you like :D

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. It worked nicely. Thank you ! But I have another issue now, would it be possible for you to help me on the problems? 
Main issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68294997/problems-for-register-page-while-using-expo-react-native-new-question
Another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68631236/warning-about-react-native-async-storage-async-storage-and-styling-for-the-login/73631449#73631449
Thank you very much !

Comment: Hi @Louay Sleman, is it possible to help me look at some other question? I really need help on these. 1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73919642/issue-with-email-verification-via-firebase-in-expo 2- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73919451/how-to-set-name-for-individual-firebase-accounts-via-expo  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend handling some common errors such as short password or invalid email format locally using Javascript than to make an API call everytime without validation.

```
const handleSignUp = async () => {
  if (email && password.length >= 8) {
    const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    console.log(user);
  } else {
    console.log("Please enter a valid email and password")
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dharmaraj, is it possible to help me on some other question? I really need help on these. 1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73919642/issue-with-email-verification-via-firebase-in-expo 2- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73919451/how-to-set-name-for-individual-firebase-accounts-via-expo  Thank you very much !