# Warning about react-native-async-storage/async-storage and styling for the login page

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Problems I am currently facing.

1. Some warning about @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

[image]

I feel this is a simple question and I am sorry for asking as I am touching expo for the very first time but how do I remove this warning?

I checked my .js files and some have `from 'react-native'`, do I change all to `from '@react-native-async-storage`? Or do I just do this `npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`. Or do I do both?

2. Styling for the page,

I have this currently: (When i never attempt to type anything new in the input boxes)

[image]

When i try to type something new in the input boxes:

[image]

I have the following code: How do i correct it so that my keyboard can be seen and the input boxes can be seen at the same time?

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView  //To prevent keyboard from blocking the writing area
        style={styles.container}
        behavior = "padding"
    >  
        <View style = {styles.inputContainer}> 
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Email"
                value={email}
                onChangeText ={text => setEmail(text)}
                styles = {styles.input} 
            />         
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Password"
                value={password}
                onChangeText ={text => setPassword(text)}
                styles = {styles.input} 
                secureTextEntry //Hide password
            />         
        </View>   
        
        <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {() => { } }
                style = {styles.button}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {handleSignUp}
                style = {[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>                       
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage` of `react-native` will be deprecated.
You should use `react-native-async-storage` instead.

[AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage)

[react-native-async-storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/)

Comment: Oh okay. Can I confirm on the steps with you as I am not so experienced using expo?

1. ``` expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage ``` on root folder
2.  Change all of  ```from 'react-native'``` to ```from '@react-native-async-storage```
Or will the system just help me do step 2 by itself? This is because ```from 'react-native'``` was in the system when i started and not I type one.